# Pass template code to child component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-forms

I have a component containing a formGroup with the following component

```
<input-number placeholder="Number" formControlName="NumericValue" required></input-number>
                  <button class="infoSuffix" type="button" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="info" (click)="OpenInfo()">
                <mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon>
              </button>
```

input number is a wrapper for `<input type="text">`

```
 <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input
      type="text"
      ..>
      </mat-form-field>
```

For the component to correctly render in need to pass the button in the childcomponent like this:

```
    <input
      type="text"
      ..>
<button class="infoSuffix" type="button" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="info" (click)="OpenInfo()">
                    <mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon>
                  </button>
      </mat-form-field>
```

How can i achive this ? Should i just pass an Config object and render it, or is there a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to implement custom form field control in the controller like described here https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#-code-ngcontrol-code-
then the following code worked

```
<mat-form-field>
<input-number placeholder="Number" formControlName="NumericValue" required></input-number>
   <button class="infoSuffix" type="button" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="info" (click)="OpenInfo()">
        <mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon>
   </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `ng-content` a concept of [content projection](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/)

input-number template

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" ..>

  <ng-content></ng-content>

</mat-form-field>
```

and in your parent comp, project the template to be rendered within the child component

parent comp

```
<input-number placeholder="Number" formControlName="NumericValue" required>
   <button class="infoSuffix" type="button" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="info" (click)="OpenInfo()">
        <mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon>
   </button>
</input-number>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Where do I need the `matSuffix` directive defined? I have my parent component in a different module than the child component, where `ng-content` is.